# How to include a list property in swagger codegen?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-codegen

swagger ignores the ComplexItems property. i need the generated axios model for my client app.

```
public class DummyModel
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // This is your complex list
    public List<ComplexItem> ComplexItems { get; set; } = new List<ComplexItem>();
}

public class ComplexItem
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

In the Api Context i added the relation.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DummyModel>()
        .HasMany(dm => dm.ComplexItems)
        .WithOne()  // or WithMany() based on your needs
        .HasForeignKey("ForeignKeyColumnIfAny");
```

In the controller i added include:

```
return await _context.DummyModels
               .Include(dm => dm.ComplexItems)
               .ToListAsync();
```

But the model looks like this whithout the list property:

```
export interface DummyModel {
   /**
    * 
    * @type {string}
    * @memberof DummyModel
    */
   id?: string;
   /**
    * 
    * @type {string}
    * @memberof DummyModel
    */
   name: string;
}
```

update:

program.cs

```
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    });
    ....
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
    c.SchemaFilter<ExcludeNullableSchemaFilter>();
});
```

DummyController

```
 [HttpPost("DummyModelTest")]
        public List<DummyModel> Post(DummyModel dummyModel)
        {

            List<DummyModel> list = new List<DummyModel> { dummyModel };
            return list;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, swagger generate the example based on the type of the WebAPI's controller method.

I suggest you could modify your controller return type as `List<DummyModel>` to see if swagger will generate the right result.

More details, you could refer to below example controller codes:

```
    [HttpPost("DummyModelTest")]
    public List<DummyModel> Post(DummyModel dummyModel)
    {

        List<DummyModel> list = new List<DummyModel> { dummyModel };
        return list;
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks, but swagger.json still does not include the complexItems property. Or is it in your swagger.json? The resulting model looks the same in my case.

Comment: Please share your controller codes and program.cs's codes which is related with swagger.

Comment: Added it. So in your model (not in return of the dummy conroller) you see the list property?

Comment: "complexItems": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ComplexItem"
                        },
                        "nullable": true, this is the generated json file codes.